# Moving concavities on a directx terrain

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm in need of some assistance here with Directx.

I'm building my project on top of the TerraTessellation Sample from the Nvidia Directx SDK.

Basically what i did was change the .dds files for the files I'm interested on displaying for the terrain.

```
V_RETURN(loadTextureFromFile(L"TerrainTessellation/color.dds",     "g_TerrainColourTexture1", pd3dDevice, g_pTerrainEffect));
V_RETURN(loadTextureFromFile(L"TerrainTessellation/normal.dds", "g_TerrainColourTexture2", pd3dDevice, g_pTerrainEffect));
V_RETURN(loadTextureFromFile(L"TerrainTessellation/GabaritoPBT.dds",      "g_DetailNoiseTexture",     pd3dDevice, g_pTerrainEffect));
```

The problem is:

When I move the camera on the X, Y and Z positions makes the concavities of the map move as well, so regarding the texture it's not on the right position as it should be.
What is happening? What could help out solving the problem?
Thanks!
Check the picture below.

[image: The bumps should be on the red region]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there was a problem with the 0 values on the heightmap and with the MIP levels they made the concavities move on its on based on distance. i took the mip levels out and it stayed great.